# How can I receive and print messages via console log when connecting to a websocket using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, websocket

I am trying to connect to websocket using Javascript, my code is:

```
var socket = new WebSocket("wss://messaging.jobdone.net/ws/293/qqyjhcze/websocket");
socket.onopen = function() {
    console.log('ok');
}

socket.addEventListener('a', function(e)
    {console.log(JSON.parse(e.data))});

socket.send('o')
```

With Chrome extension I receive this output:

```
a["{\"t\":\"auth.token\",\"b\":{\"cid\":\"845ba213-a0c2-4073-9257-7e3883a8c4d2\",\"token\":\"cda495f9fd6e6a547553b91381d58e3c601029989c371cdf39ec3152f3a3e2a7\"}}"]
```

With my js code I receive this:

```
undefined
```

How can I receive the same output like the Chrome extension shows, when I try to connect to this wss server?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

socket.send(e.data)

Sending the data to server